# Prove or disprove: Does Fréchet-differentiable function with a local extremum satisfy $D_yf(a) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: [0, 1] \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Fréchet differentiable, and suppose that $f$ has a local extremum at $a = (1, 1)^T$. Then, $D_yf(a) = 0$.

My idea:
To show or refute the statement, let's consider the counterexample:

Let the function $f: [0, 1] \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x, y) = y$. This means that $f$ assigns the value $y$ to every point $(x, y)$. Note that $f$ is constant along the $y$-axis.

We will check if $f$ has a local extremum at $a = (1, 1)^T$:

To have a local extremum, $f$ must reach a maximum or minimum in the neighborhood of $a$. Let's consider the neighborhood of $a$:

$U = \{(x, y) \in [0, 1] \times \mathbb{R} \, | \, |x - 1| < \delta, |y - 1| < \epsilon\}$

Since $f$ is constant along the $y$-axis, the function value does not change as long as $x$ lies in $[0, 1]$. Therefore, $f(x, y) = 1$ for all $(x, y) \in U$.

Hence, $f$ does not have a local extremum at $a$ since $f$ has the same function value throughout the neighborhood of $a$.

Now, let's check if $\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}} (a) = 0$:

$\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}} (a)$ indicates how $f$ behaves in the $y$-direction near $a$. Since $f$ is constant along the $y$-axis, the function value of $f$ does not change as $y$ changes. Therefore, $\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}} (a) = 0$.

This means that the statement "$\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}} (a) = 0$" is true, even though $f$ does not have a local extremum at $a$. Thus, the statement has been refuted.

Is that correct?

Comment: $f$ is constant along the $y$-axis??

Comment: how can I fix this logical problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof $(1,1)$ is not a local extremum is wrong. $f$ is not constantly equal to $1$ for all elements of $U$. $f$ takes values in the range $(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$... but it's still true $(1,1)$ is not an extremum.

The statement also has *not* been refuted and it's *not* true that $\partial f/\partial y=0$. $\partial_2f\equiv1$, in fact. And even if this were true, the statement is:

> If [extremum] then [zero derivative]

Whereas you gave a (false) example of:

> [zero derivative] but [not extremum]

Which isn't a refutation.

The statement is actually true.

Take a differentiable $f:[0,1]\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$. If $(1,1)$ is a local extremum, then there is some $\delta>0$ such that for all $(x,y)$ with $1-x<\delta,|y-1|<\delta$, $f(x,y)\le f(1,1)$ (without loss of generality, we suppose it is a maximum). Then fixing in particular $x=1$ we have, for $y\in(1,1+\delta)$: $$\frac{f(1,y)-f(1,1)}{y-1}\le0$$And for $y\in(1-\delta,1)$: $$\frac{f(1,y)-f(1,1)}{y-1}\ge0$$Taking the limit as $y\to1$ finds that $\partial_y f(1,1)$ is both $\ge0$ and $\le0$, so it must be zero - as desired.